# Apache POI : How to change system separator

Tags: java, excel, apache-poi

I have requirement in which I have to change the decimal separator from `.` to `,` for cell type **Number**

I am using stream workbook (SXSSFWorkbook) and poi version `3.17`.

I can do this by changing the option from excel as -
[image]

Is there any way I can implement that?

Comment: This option is not stored on workbook level. It is an application option. If set, then it is used for each workbook this Excel application opens. So no, it cannot be set using `apache poi` because `apache poi` only creates Excel workbooks. It does not interact with any Excel application.

Comment: yeah, I believe so. Thanks anyways :)